# Backup with power control

Tags: backup, power

How can I have a server power on auxiliary hard disks for a backup, and then power them off when the backup is complete? This is for a home office, so nothing too expensive please.

Answer (score 0):

It is conceivable that you could find a UPS that allows remote power-off / power-on of the load using USB.  I don't know of a home / home-office UPS that does this off the top of my head; mostly USB is used for sensing UPS status.

Other than that, there are networked PDU (Power Distribution Units), but the ones I'm aware of are in the $1k range and probably unsuited for your use in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

There are devices like the [International Power Controller (IPC)](http://www.bomara.com/cps/ipc.htm) which have a serial interface and can turn power on and off via a RS232 serial connection (or other connections including phone on some devices) for around $100.  These are about the cheapest devices I have seen as their new price.

However, you can often find Ethernet or serial controlled power strips on ebay for much less than this, with multiple ports.  You'll probably need to find a unit through regular web searching and then look for it on ebay.  I tried some searches, but the products I use these days (APC-7900) are all $100 and up.  Years ago I found several for $50 or less each.  I couldn't come up with a good search or category that would produce many of them, but "network power" had one that was currently $60.